# keytool SHA256 (android keystore) not generating

Tags: keytool, sha256, android-keystore

I have been using SHA1 only so far. Now I need SHA256 so that I tried to get it from the keystore file which is made from Android studio.
Until now, I couldn't get the result. 
The result is like this.

```
Engineerui:Docs/B0006$ keytool -v -list -keystore ./AndAppRelease.keystore
keystore 암호를 입력하십시오:  

Keystore 유형: JKS
Keystore 공급자: SUN

Keystore에는 1 항목이 포함되어 있습니다.

별칭 이름: theAliasName
작성일: keyStore.getCreationDate(alias)
항목 유형: PrivateKeyEntry
인증서 체인 길이: 1
인증서[1]:
소유자: O=Company Inc., L=aCity, ST=aState, C=US
발급자: O=Company Inc., L=aCity, ST=aState, C=US
일련 번호: aSerialnum
유효 기간 시작: Fri Sep 21 15:39:04 KST 2012 끝: Sat Sep 09 15:39:04 KST 2062
인증 지문:
     MD5:  aMD5String
     SHA1: aSHA1String
     서명 알고리즘 이름: SHA1withRSA
     버전: 3


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Any idea or thought? 
Thank you very much!